# InetAddress Ip address lookup from hostname Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, dns, hostname, inetaddress

I'm trying to get the IP address of a computer(or Raspberry Pi) from its hostname from an Android App using InetAddress,The problem is when i type "www.google.com" for example it works but when I try "PC****" which is my PC hostname (got it from the cmd command hostname) it doesn't work 
Please Help me

```
 public void SearchMachines(View v) {
     String netAddress = null;
     TextView localTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvScaned);
     try
      {
       netAddress = new NetTask().execute("www.google.com").get();
       localTextView.setText("Address: " + netAddress);
      }
      catch (Exception e1)
       {
        e1.printStackTrace();
       }


 }
 public class NetTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            InetAddress addr = null;
            try
            {
                addr = InetAddress.getByName(params[0]);
            }

            catch (UnknownHostException e)
            {
                            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return addr.getHostAddress();
        }
    }
 ![Here is Logcat][1]
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" in what way? Does it crash? Does it show no IP address? ...

Comment: "Unfortunately App_mobile has stopped"

Comment: I tested it from my phone not emulator

Comment: Then the logcat will tell you why it crashed. Please post the relevant part of it.

Answer (score 0):

`return addr.getHostAddress();`. Even after a catch you are using `addr` but it is `null` then so you have a `NullPointerException`.

Put that statement in the try block and put `return e.getMessage();` in the catch block.